# Using preg_match_all to find a string with an escaped apostrophe

Tags: php, regex, string, escaping, preg-match-all

I'm trying to preg_match_all a string that I'm getting from user input that has an apostrophe in it. First I tested it out on a regular string to see if it'll match or not, and it does. However, when I tried to test it out on the same user input string, it doesn't work. I think it's because the apostrophe in the user input gets escaped, before I compared them.

```
$temp1 = "I'm a person.";

preg_match_all('/I\'m\s+(.+)/i', $temp1, $matches);
$temp1 = $matches[1][0];
echo $temp1;
```

**output** :
a person.

However, since I'm getting $temp from user input and escaping the apostrophe, it escapes the apostrophe when it takes it out, and therefore it doesn't match:

```
$temp2 = "I\'m a person.";

preg_match_all('/I\'m\s+(.+)/i', $temp2, $matches);
$temp2 = $matches[1][0];
echo $temp2;
```

**output** : null.

How do I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
preg_match_all('/I\\\\\'m\s+(.+)/i', $temp2, $matches);
echo $matches[1][0];
```

**Output:**

```
a person.
```

Use `\\\\` to match a single backslash in input.

Comment: I have to say that all these escaping is kind of weird, lol. but it works. thanks.